# How can store an array all values less than the first 3?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this example:

```
var array=[0.1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
```

What I want is to store it in a variable only those values

```
var newArray=[3,4,6,7,8,9]
```

Of course, this must be dynamic ... regardless of the number of elements to store more than the first 3 items.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far

Comment: yes,sorry for my explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript's `slice`:

```
var array = [0.1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9];
var newArray = array.slice(2);
// [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

> **Usage**: *arr.slice([begin[, end]])*
>
> `slice` does not alter. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array.